# ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated

Tags: pulseaudio

If I run multiple `vlc`s in parallel (in the order of 30) I get:

```
[00005615b670fe80] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection terminated
[00005615b67d5e80] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection terminated
[00005615b670f570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated
```

If I close one `vlc` I can open another with no problem.

It smells as if there is a limit in PulseAudio in the number of clients it accepts (maybe 32?).

How can I test if this is the case, and how can I avoid the error in the future?